# For custom form components, is it possible to use DefaultValueAccessor instead of ControlValueAccessor?

Tags: angular

I need to be able to use the `formControlName` directive for my custom component.

I've been reading through the multiple SO questions about implementing `ControlValueAccessor` for a child component, and it all seems very fragile.

A lot of the examples are transforming `<div>` or `<span>` elements into form elements, and so it makes sense to implement all the functionality expected by `ControlValueAccessor`.

However, my component is just using the native `<input>` element. I'm creating a separate component because I want to use some icons with the input, and I obviously don't want to copy/paste the icon css everywhere.

I've come across the `DefaultValueAccessor` class which seems to be what's used by angular for all the native input elements. Can I leverage this behavior somehow for my custom component as well?

I just don't want to replicate this functionality. It could be difficult to maintain it over the long term with regards to bugs and various browser behavior. I would rather just use the functionality that's already associated with the native inputs.

### Edit

Here's the code snippet of `<jg-search>` (my custom component):

```
<div>
    <svg>
        <!-- some content -->
    </svg>
    <label for="search">Search</label>
    <input id="search" type="text"></input>
    <svg>
        <!-- some content -->
    </svg>
</div>
```

I want to be able to just call it this way in a form: `<jg-search formControlName="keyword">`.

This is possible by implementing `ControlValueAccessor` in the SearchComponent. But since I'm just using the native `<input type="text">`, I don't want to reimplement the functionality already defined in `DefaultValueAccessor`.

Comment: It might help if you include a precise description on what you want to accomplish as well as snippets and code example you have tried and where they fall short exactly

Comment: @Z.Bagley I've added a code snippet. As you can see, it's nothing fancy. So far, I've tried extending `DefaultValueAccessor` in the SearchComponent, but I'm running into issues with regards to its dependencies. Either way, I don't think extending it is the right approach, but I honestly do not know.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

One possible solution could be using `ngDefaultControl` attribute on your custom component:

```
<div [formGroup]="form">
    <jg-search formControlName="x" ngDefaultControl></jg-search>
                                   ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
</div>
```

now all you need to do is to link your `input` element with existing FormControl as follows:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'jg-search',
  template: `
   <input [formControl]="ngControl.control">
  `
})
export class MyInput {
  constructor(public ngControl: NgControl) {}
}
```

For more detals see **[Ng-run Example](https://ng-run.com/edit/NFwmXDfevdpThS0dizzA)**

Comment: You still need to add `ngDefaultControl` each time you use it.. is there a way to use it like a native input while leveraging `DefaultValueAccessor`?

Answer (score 2):

As a form developer, I'd like to have a simple way to append units to my input form field so that I can minimize my HTML code.

I have HTML (with Bootstrap) that looks like this:

```html
  <div class="input-group">
    <input type="number" formControlName="weight"/>
    <div class="input-group-append">
         <span class="input-group-text">lbs</span>
    </div>
  </div>
```

I'd rather write this:

```html
<inp-with-units formControlName="weight" units="lbs"></inp-with-units>
```

[image: form control with number (38.2) and units ('lbs')]

The accepted answer from @yurzui is straightforward, simple and a great demonstration of how to do a little with most of the angular form code. One part bothered me, I didn't want to have to add `ngDefaultControl` to my top level HTML. His answer sent me looking in the right direction.

Meanwhile, @gjvatsalya has a point about code reuse. For example, when I looked at `DefaultValueAccessor` [sources](https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/master/packages/forms/src/directives/default_value_accessor.ts) I found code that handles a [`CompositionEvent`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51226598/what-is-javascripts-compositionevent-please-give-examples) for AndroidOS mobile. I didn't even know this tech existed. Point made, use as much Angular as we can.

yurzui's solution places the `DefaultValueAccessor` (DVA) on the calling html. Instead, let's place it on the internal template input DOM element and also implement the `ControlValueAccessor` interface to bridge over to the DVA. Why put the DVA inside the HTML template code? (1) Having to remember to add `ngDefaultControl` every time seems like an opportunity for errors. (2) `ControlValueAccessor` interface isn't likely to change soon, and if it does, the bridged code also needs to change. We won't be surprised in the future.

This code does one other thing, it ensures that the *View => Model* change notifications are re-typed as `number` if they look like numbers. This hints at more interesting behavior we could do with `<input>` wrappers like this class.

```js
@Component({
  selector: 'inp-with-units',
  template: `
  <div class="input-group">
    <input type="number" ngDefaultControl/>
    <div class="input-group-append" *ngIf="units.length">
         <span class="input-group-text">{{units}}</span>
    </div>
  </div>
`})
export class InpNumWithUnits implements ControlValueAccessor {
  @Input('units') units: string = "";
  @ViewChild(DefaultValueAccessor, {static: true}) dva: DefaultValueAccessor;

  constructor(@Self() private ngControl: NgControl) {
    this.ngControl.valueAccessor = this;
  }

  // Component uses type 'number'. Angular FormControlDirective handles
  // View => Model type conversion (onChange sends number). We wrap the
  // onChange notifier so we, too, can do a type conversion on the value.
  wrap(fn) { return (v) => fn(v === "" || isNaN(v) ? v : +v) }

  // *** ControlValueAccessor Methods
  setDisabledState(d: boolean) { this.dva.setDisabledState(d); }
  writeValue(value: any)       { this.dva.writeValue(value); }
  registerOnChange(fn: any)    { this.dva.registerOnChange(this.wrap(fn)); }
  registerOnTouched(fn: any)   { this.dva.registerOnTouched(fn); }
}
```

---

ETA (2020 08 13): Looks like there's a [bug](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/20230) related to Custom Control's and suppressing value change notifications. If you're using the above solution and need to prevent value change propagation, be advised.

---

ETA (2020 08 28): workaround for this bug is to not use `valueChanges` and instead add a user input event call to the HTML `(input)="trackChanges($event)"`. You can add it as follows:

```
<inp-with-units formControlName="weight"
                units="lbs"
                (input)="trackChanges($event)">
</inp-with-units>
```