# Render nested components without host element container - Separate SVG parts into Different components

Tags: angular, svg, angular-directive, angular-components

I have a component with an SVG element, I am trying to separate the parts of that SVG into different components.
The nested components need to be created dynamically from the parent component, this is because of the fact I am building the whole SVG graphic from a json file that determines which nested components (SVG nested shapes) need to be added.

To create the components dynamically I am using ComponentFactoryResolver and the ViewContainerRef
from @angular/core

```
@Component({
selector: 'skick-player',
 templateUrl: './player.component.html',
 styleUrls: ['./player.component.scss'],
})
export class PlayerComponent implements OnInit, AfterViewInit {

@ViewChild('svgContainer', { read: ViewContainerRef }) container;

constructor( private resolver: ComponentFactoryResolver) {}

  performFrame() {

      ....
     //Add nested component
      const factory = this.resolver.resolveComponentFactory(
        BackDropItemComponent
      );
      const componentRef = this.container.createComponent(factory);
      componentRef.instance.imagePath = objectUrl;
    }
  }
});
```

}

The problem is that angular wraps the nested component within a div:

```
<div _nghost-qon-c42="" skick-back-drop-item="" class="ng-star-inserted">
```

So it is not rendered because of the special element tags created. If that div element is removed, it renders the nested SVG properly.

I know i can render the nested component as a directive and it would work, something like this:

```
<svg>
<svg:g skick-back-drop-item />
</svg>
```

but in my use case, the controller needs to be rendered dynamically from the parent component, so that approach does not work for me.

**Maybe is there a way to render (add the nested controller) as a directive from the parent component pro-grammatically (bear in mind the nested component has @input properties) ?**

or

**Is it possible to have invisible component containers? Render the content of the nested component without any container?**

---

Parent template:

```
<div class="patch-overlay" cdkDrag>
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"
    xmlns:svgjs="http://svgjs.dev/svgjs" width="100%" height="100%">
    <<ng-container #svgContainer></ng-container>>
</svg>
</div>
```

Nested Component Template (Example):

```
<svg width="400" height="110">
<rect [attr.width]="width" height="100" style="fill:rgb(0,0,255);stroke-width:3;stroke:rgb(0,0,0)" />
</svg>
```

Comment: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-fyna9e?file=src%2Fapp%2Fhello.component.ts

Please check this example now this time angular did not wrap programmatically created component in div

Comment: @hanan, thanks, it wrap it within the <hello> container, that is why the rectangle does not render in your example. I found that adding the following CSS rule: hello {
  display: contents;
} do the trick but I do not like that approach to much

Comment: @D.B, if the selector of your component is enclosed by `[` and `]`: `selector: '[skick-back-drop-item]',` you can appli to any html tag

Answer (score 5):

Since this shows up as the most recent on the first page of google for the question here is the workaround that seems to work in all cases: using display contents.

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-my-component',
  templateUrl: './my-component.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./my-component.component.sass'],
  host: {
    style: "display: contents"
  }
})
export class MyComponent {}
```

This works by telling the browser to act as if the host element isnt there at all; it will still be part of the html if you do inspect element but it will not be part of any rendering/sizing/position considerations.
P.S. this does have an advantage over not including it at all in the html, it is still a selectable html element for CSS

Comment: Wow, you're a life saver. Host elements in the DOM is one of the most frustrating aspects of Angular and sometimes makes styling soo difficult!

Answer (score 2):

I've tried to do what you're doing. My mistakes include building specialized FormGroup components (don't do that). Recently, I built a component using [ControlValueAccessor](https://angular.io/api/forms/ControlValueAccessor#controlvalueaccessor) and it works really well and serves my purpose.

I haven't built anything with `ng-template` and its associated features, like `ngTemplateOutlet`. However, I suspect this might help you. `ng-template` gets moved out of the way in the DOM, which is what you're looking for.

Here's Angular Univeristy's [explanation](https://blog.angular-university.io/angular-ng-template-ng-container-ngtemplateoutlet/). I also find Netanel Basel has great [info](https://netbasal.com/create-modular-components-with-angular-structural-directives-1a5198d9ab7d).

If you want to try the CVA route, last week I just got done with recoding on a project and did a bunch of research here on SO. Found a question that touched on what I wanted to do and went back and wrote a [new answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62563899/314114) that worked for me. Check it out, it might give you what you need.

Comment: Thanks @Andrew. ng-template is removed from the DOM for for some cases like when implementing if/else scenario, but a new div container is added as a wrapper when injecting the component dynamically from the controller.So, Unfortunately that approach didn't work for me. :(

Answer (score -1):

Building on TurtleKwitty's [great answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69470344/2501304), their exact solution gave me the error [Use @HostBinding or @HostListener rather than the `host` metadata property](https://github.com/angular-eslint/angular-eslint/blob/master/packages/eslint-plugin/docs/rules/no-host-metadata-property.md)

I solved by moving it to my component's `.scss` file, like so:

```scss
:host {
  display: contents;
}
```

Hope that helps someone else!